# How to look at an inequality and understand the function’s limit?

Tags: limits

> For this inequality $ 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} \ < \frac {x \sin x}{2-2\cos x} < 1$ holds for all values of x close to zero. What does the $\lim_{x \to \ 0} \frac {x \sin x}{2-2\cos x}$ mean ?

I’ve just started learning limits and the formal definition / squeeze theorem of limit confuses me.

How to I look at such an inequality and understand the limits (when $x$ approaches 0) of that function $f(x) =  \frac {x \sin x}{2-2\cos x} $

I know that  $\lim_{x \to \ 0} \frac {x \sin x}{2-2\cos x} = 1$ Because $\ sin$ And $\cos$ is bounded by 1 and -1, but how do I understand the rest of the inequality and limits?

Answer (score 2):

You use what is called "the sandwich theorem". i.e. if

$g(x)\leq\,f(x)\,\leq\,h(x)$ for all $x$ in a neighborhood

$(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0})\bigcup\,(x_{0},x_{0}+\delta)$, and

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_{0}}g(x)=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)=A$ then

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_{0}}f(x)=A$. And in your case $A=1$

Comment: I learned it as the "squeeze theorem", but same thing.